# How to ignore rubocop check when using guard-rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard, rubocop

When I add a `guard-rspec` gem and set the `Guardfile` as this:

```
guard :rspec, cmd: 'bundle exec rspec' do
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')                        { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
end
```

Then run `rubocop` to check:

```
rake rubocop:rubocop
```

It showed:

```
Guardfile:5:9: C: Use %r only for regular expressions matching more than 1 '/' character.
watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Should I try to find a way to rewrite the regular code or write a ignore code to `.rubocop.yml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed to `watch(%r{^spec/(.*)/(.*)\.rb$})`, then it passed.

Answer (score 1):

Rubocop tells you that the extended regex notation `%r{}` should only be used if the regex itself contains more than 1 `/` character. Otherwise you should use `//` notation and escape the `/` symbol

You can rewrite the line to `watch(/^spec\/.+_spec\.rb$/)` to get rid of the warning without changing the regex itself